# Which bash scripts are executed when a terminal is started?

Tags: terminal, rhel, environment-variables

I'm running RHEL 7.4 with bash shell and GNOME Terminal and am trying to figure out why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains paths to certain directories. I removed `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` but after restarting the terminal I find that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is still populated.

More peculiar is that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains paths to locations which I've created like `/home/jodag/my_local/lib`. I thought deleting `.bashrc` would stop these values from being loaded but it hasn't.

Is there a way to list all the scripts being executed when the terminal starts, or possibly some other way to track down what is setting my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: I'd guess it's possible that the process which starts the terminal emulator still has `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set and this gets inherited by `bash` when you start it?

Comment: I think you're right. I re-logged and now things are working as I would expect. Looking through my old `~/.bash_profile` I found that it was executing `~/.bashrc` which meant that `~/.bashrc` was being executed twice, once on log-in and once when the terminal started.

Answer (score 0):

Your display manager and your window manager each run system-wide init scripts and per-user init scripts. Consult their man pages. Among the usual suspects are `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession`.